# Is there any option to get typeahead.js values by php form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to get [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) input values by PHP to echo them.

I simply try to create form and echo the `$_POST` of this input.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $_POST['tags'];
    }
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();


    jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
      name: 'tags',
      displayKey: 'name',
      source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('autowords.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
          data = $.parseJSON(data);
          return process(data);
        });
      },
      afterSelect :function (item){
        tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="typeahead tm-input form-control tm-input-info"/>
 <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I expected to get the tags I have wrote but nothing echo.

**EDIT:** I decided move to jQuery autocomplete.

Comment: Last time i checked they aren't doing dev on typeahead anymore and there were open bugs with it. I haven't looked in a while, but you might want to think about using jQuery's autocomplete instead of typeahead.

Comment: @bassxzero I got you suggest and its totaly comfortable! thanks for you advice.

Comment: What do you get when you do a dump of `$_POST`?

Comment: @charlietfl actually I create a new one so I can check it. I work now with autocomplete jQuery.